# Cannot add a trigger in Zabbix 5.0

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

When I try to create a trigger, it shows an error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inAmg.png)

Someone, please help me to resolve this issue.

I was trying to add monitoring domain expiration in Zabbix 5.0.  I created a custom template to monitor domain expiration and added an item to that template but when trying to create the trigger I faced the problem.

Comment: what is the item type?

Comment: Item Type "Zabbix Agent"